# Alfresco 5.1.x community edition integration with PHP Application

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am new to alfresco i created workflow process using eclipse `acitiviti kickstart` in the workflow i need to pass value to external PHP application get response from `PHP Application` append into workflow form is this possible? and how ?

Comment: You could setup a java service task in you workflow and have it do a RESTful request to your php server !

Comment: Thanks , can you suggest some reference for the same